# JOIN com LIMIT em Query

Tags: postgresql

Tenho as seguintes tabelas com as informações abaixo:

**RESERVA**:

```
id| checkin    | checkout   | titular | valor
--+------------+------------+---------+--------
1 | 2018-09-01 | 2018-09-02 | BOOKING | 300
2 | 2018-09-03 | 2018-09-05 | BOOKING | 600
```

**HOSPEDES**:

```
id| nome    | reserva
--+---------+---------
1 | FULANO  | 1
2 | FULANA  | 1
3 | SICRANO | 2
4 | SICRANA | 2
```

Com essa query:

```
SELECT R.ID, R.TITULAR, R.CHECKIN, R.CHECKOUT, H.NOME FROM RESERVA R
JOIN HOSPEDES H ON H.RESERVA = R.ID
```

Tenho o resultado:

```
id  titular checkin     checkout    nome
1   BOOKING 2018-09-01  2018-09-02  FULANO
1   BOOKING 2018-09-01  2018-09-02  FULANA
2   BOOKING 2018-09-03  2018-09-05  SICRANO
2   BOOKING 2018-09-03  2018-09-05  SICRANA
```

Gostaria de uma query que me retornasse apenas 1 correspondência na tabela **HOSPEDES**, ou seja, apenas o primeiro hospede de cada reserva.

Assim:

```
id  titular checkin     checkout    nome
1   BOOKING 2018-09-01  2018-09-02  FULANO
2   BOOKING 2018-09-03  2018-09-05  SICRANO
```

É possível fazer um JOIN com LIMIT 1 ?

Segue Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a91b0/2

Answer (score 1):

Use essa consulta. Ela pega o primeiro hóspede pelo ID, ou seja, o menor ID. Para cada reserva, pega o menor.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Reserva r
 JOIN Hospedes h ON r.id = h.reserva
 AND h.id = (SELECT MIN(h2.id) from hospedes h2 where h2.reserva = r.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Selecionando com **Distinct on** e depois usando **ORDER** você consegue o resultado esperado.

```
SELECT  Distinct on(R.ID) R.TITULAR, R.CHECKIN, R.CHECKOUT, H.NOME FROM RESERVA R
JOIN HOSPEDES H ON H.RESERVA = R.ID ORDER BY R.ID
```

Comment: Não posso ordenar pelo R.ID, tenho que ordenar pelo checkin, existe outra forma?

Comment: O primeiro de cada reserva seria pelo ID, certo? veja minha resposta se funciona.

Comment: O seu checkin tem um único ID por dia? Ou no mesmo dia (2018-09-01 por exemplo) pode existir mais de um ID?